# How to sort on value in list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, csv, filter

I've got the following data:

```
sdlist :
['id', 'gen', 'age', 'mar', 'loc', 'inc', 'iscr', 'escr']
[51, 'F', 46, 'M', 0, 15100, 531, 555]
[52, 'M', 29, 'M', 2, 14200, 673, 633]
[53, 'M', 25, 'S', 0, 22200, 742, 998]
[54, 'M', 36, 'M', 2, 1000, 677, 646]
[55, 'F', 99, 'S', 0, 10600, 608, 998]
[56, 'F', 45, 'M', 2, 6100, 710, 743]
[57, 'M', 99, 'M', 2, 16500, 679, 646]
[58, 'F', 37, 'M', 0, 7400, 637, 683]
[59, 'M', 45, 'S', 0, 22800, 683, 998]
[60, 'M', 22, 'S', 0, 6400, 699, 998]
```

And now I would like to make a function so that for example if I give the function a value `'age'`, I get this same list but filtered on age. So let's say the function is called `func(field)` en I would call it with 'age': `func('age')`, the result I want to have is:

```
[60, 'M', 22, 'S', 0, 6400, 699, 998]
[53, 'M', 25, 'S', 0, 22200, 742, 998]
[52, 'M', 29, 'M', 2, 14200, 673, 633]
[54, 'M', 36, 'M', 2, 1000, 677, 646]
[58, 'F', 37, 'M', 0, 7400, 637, 683]
[56, 'F', 45, 'M', 2, 6100, 710, 743]
[59, 'M', 45, 'S', 0, 22800, 683, 998]
[51, 'F', 46, 'M', 0, 15100, 531, 555]
[55, 'F', 99, 'S', 0, 10600, 608, 998]
[57, 'M', 99, 'M', 2, 16500, 679, 646]
```

Is there a way to do this

Comment: By filtered do you mean sorted?

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by "filtered"? The result of `func('age')` above seems to be the same as the original data, except that it's sorted by `'age'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do it without `pandas`:

```
data = [
    [51, 'F', 46, 'M', 0, 15100, 531, 555],
    [52, 'M', 29, 'M', 2, 14200, 673, 633],
    [53, 'M', 25, 'S', 0, 22200, 742, 998],
    [54, 'M', 36, 'M', 2, 1000, 677, 646],
    [55, 'F', 99, 'S', 0, 10600, 608, 998],
    [56, 'F', 45, 'M', 2, 6100, 710, 743],
    [57, 'M', 99, 'M', 2, 16500, 679, 646],
    [58, 'F', 37, 'M', 0, 7400, 637, 683],
    [59, 'M', 45, 'S', 0, 22800, 683, 998],
    [60, 'M', 22, 'S', 0, 6400, 699, 998],
]

sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

and we can also define a function which can be used with a key:

```
def filter(key):
    index = ['id', 'gen', 'age', 'mar', 'loc', 'inc', 'iscr', 'escr'].index(key)
    return index
```

The call of `sorted` changes to

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[filter('age')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas Dataframe here:

```
def _filter(df, param):
    df.sort_values([param], inplace=True)
    return df

df = pd.read_csv('csv_inputfile.csv')
df_filtered = _filter(df, 'age')
print(df_filtered)

   id gen  age mar  loc    inc  iscr  escr
9  60   M   22   S    0   6400   699   998
2  53   M   25   S    0  22200   742   998
1  52   M   29   M    2  14200   673   633
3  54   M   36   M    2   1000   677   646
7  58   F   37   M    0   7400   637   683
5  56   F   45   M    2   6100   710   743
8  59   M   45   S    0  22800   683   998
0  51   F   46   M    0  15100   531   555
4  55   F   99   S    0  10600   608   998
6  57   M   99   M    2  16500   679   646
```